# Load kernel modules from neighbor kernel

Tags: virtualbox, kernel-modules

I use Manjaro Linux based on Arch. It has several kernels. The regular kernel is 5.15.15-MANJARO works fine with VitualBox. The second one is 5.15-AnboxMod.
I need to share `vboxdrv.ko.xz` and other VirtualBox modules to kernel AnboxMod.

How to do that?

I tried to reinstall VirtualBox but it does not install its ko's to all the kernels, just to default one.

Upd. I also tried to install AUR anbox-modules-dkms-git to default kernel but that modules halt the system during loading MANJARO kernel with Oops, they do not work with it. But look like work fine in AnboxMod.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/vboxconfig` is a simple script which references `/usr/src/kernel-modules/virtualbox/src/Makefile`. It should not be difficult to modify them to take a different kernel option. You may get away with just changing `INCLUDE="/lib/modules/\`uname -r\`/build/include"`

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/usr/sbin/vboxconfig': No such file or directory`

Comment: `which vboxconfig` should tell you where it is installed, and it should be installed.

Comment: Seems it is a problem of my distribution `pacman -F vboxconfig` should show a package which contains that file, but it returns nothing. So the `pkgfile vboxconfig` show nothing.

Comment: in Arch linux it is named `vboxreload`